# Using the output of `combn` to rename lists

Tags: r

I have the following data which looks like:

```
   Pza_de_Espana Escuelas_Aguirre Av_Ramon_y_Cajal Arturo_Soria C_Farolillo Casa_de_Campo Barajas
1             12               29               26           27          19             4      31
2             40               42               55           49          41            25      53
3             51               51               73           57          56            51      60
4             53               52               65           56          64            64      56
5             46               46               59           50          53            34      65
6             30               34               39           39          34            20      50
7             31               39               40           28          37            28      37
```

I can run the following to get the first stage linear regression fitted values for each combination of the columns.

```
firstStage <- combn(names(data)[-1], 2, FUN = function(x)
  lm(reformulate(x[1], response = x[2]), data = data), simplify = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
firstStagePreds <- firstStage %>% 
  map(., ~ pluck(., "fitted.values"))

firstStageFittedValues <- firstStagePreds %>% 
  bind_cols()
```

Which gives me:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 171
    ...1  ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9 ...10 ...11 ...12 ...13 ...14 ...15 ...16 ...17 ...18
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  33.1  25.7  19.1  1.93  35.6  28.7  35.1  25.0  19.5  22.8  30.1  14.8  23.2  81.6  19.2  5.92  14.3  74.6
 2  53.4  43.8  43.0 31.7   50.1  47.3  57.3  47.1  37.9  42.5  46.0  32.8  43.8  81.7  42.4 23.8   29.8  74.9
 3  67.5  56.4  59.6 52.2   60.1  60.2  72.7  62.4  50.6  56.2  57.0  45.3  58.1  81.7  58.4 36.2   40.6  75.2
 4  69.0  57.8  61.4 54.5   61.2  61.6  74.4  64.1  52.0  57.7  58.2  46.6  59.7  81.7  60.2 37.6   41.8  75.2
 5  59.7  49.4  50.4 40.8   54.5  53.0  64.2  53.9  43.5  48.6  50.9  38.3  50.2  81.7  49.5 29.3   34.6  75.0
```

Where the column names are `...1  ...2  ...3` etc. I would like to use the `combn(names(data)...` to rename the lists in the `firstStage` part of the code. Then I can use the `bind_cols(.id = "myListNames")` to have more meaningful column names. So how can I use the output of the `combn` store them and rename the list?

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Pza_de_Espana = c(12, 40, 51, 53, 46, 30, 31, 
30, 26, 47), Escuelas_Aguirre = c(29, 42, 51, 52, 46, 34, 39, 
31, 39, 41), Av_Ramon_y_Cajal = c(26, 55, 73, 65, 59, 39, 40, 
49, 47, 56), Arturo_Soria = c(27, 49, 57, 56, 50, 39, 28, 25, 
35, 50), C_Farolillo = c(19, 41, 56, 64, 53, 34, 37, 22, 25, 
50), Casa_de_Campo = c(4, 25, 51, 64, 34, 20, 28, 7, 9, 38), 
    Barajas = c(31, 53, 60, 56, 65, 50, 37, 41, 36, 54), Pza_del_Carmen = c(24, 
    46, 59, 63, 54, 35, 43, 39, 40, 47), Moratalaz = c(35, 62, 
    76, 69, 67, 48, 37, 39, 47, 66), Cuatro_Caminos = c(19, 40, 
    65, 64, 52, 33, 50, 37, 33, 51), Barrio_de_Pilar = c(23, 
    40, 53, 52, 40, 29, 28, 19, 31, 41), Vallecas = c(21, 44, 
    55, 56, 54, 37, 28, 26, 33, 47), Mendez_Alvaro = c(24, 44, 
    55, 59, 51, 32, 51, 42, 31, 51), Retiro = c(13, 31, 44, 50, 
    36, 22, 30, 22, 21, 37), Ensanche_Vallecas = c(21, 47, 55, 
    56, 62, 34, 32, 29, 32, 45), Plaza_Eliptica = c(81.989743981193, 
    81.9187518755066, 81.8477597698195, 81.7767676641325, 81.7057755584454, 
    81.6347834527583, 81.5637913470712, 81.4927992413841, 81.421807135697, 
    81.3508150300099), Sanchinarro = c(16, 52, 61, 56, 46, 30, 
    28, 25, 33, 48), El_Pardo = c(7, 28, 30, 42, 31, 16, 12, 
    8, 13, 29), Parque_Juan_Carlos_1 = c(17, 36, 41, 41, 35, 
    27, 18, 12, 20, 32), Tres_Olivos = c(76.7710873995529, 76.3531164480543, 
    75.935145496561, 75.5171745450677, 75.0992035935744, 74.6812326420812, 
    74.2632616905879, 73.8452907390946, 73.4273197876013, 73.009348836108
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return only the fitted values from `combn`.

```
library(dplyr)

combn(names(data)[-1], 2, FUN = function(x) {
    model <- lm(reformulate(x[1], response = x[2]), data = data)
    tibble(!!paste(x, collapse = ' vs ') := model$fitted.values)
}, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

Comment: My problem is related to the names of the columns. I don't know which regression the fitted values correspond to. If I can rename the lists in the `firstStage` part I will know which fitted values correspond to which regression output.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!